# django database path : no unsupported opperand type

Tags: python, django, database

In the django settings.py, the database is by default :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

But when i do in python `a={'a':'a'/'b'}`, i get the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'.
How come the error doesnt show up in django?

I would like to define a different path for my database, in a subfolder so as django automatically create the subfolder and the sqlite database.

How can i do that?

Comment: Because `BASE_DIR` is not a `str`ing, but a `Path` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when i do in python `a={'a':'a'/'b'}`, I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'`. How come the error doesnt show up in django?

Because `BASE_DIR` is not a `str`ing, but a [**`Path`** object <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use). For this object, the `__div__` method has been defined, and it thus uses `some_path / 'foo.sqlite3'` to join the path at the left side with the right string. Indeed, for example:

```
>>> Path('/etc') / 'foo' / 'bar.data'
PosixPath('/etc/foo/bar.data')
```

> I would like to define a different path for my database, in a subfolder so as django automatically create the subfolder and the sqlite database...how can i do that?

You can specify a different path, for example with:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'subdir' / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, if i do a django manage.py makemigrations and django manage.py migrate after i change the path but also after i have already done that with a previous path, i get the error RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': unable to open database file
 for makmigrations and django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file for migrate

Comment: django doesnt take care of creating the subdir...it needs to be done manually